# Open Distro alert plugin elasticsearch exception

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, alert

I trying open distro alert plugin for dockerized kibana and elastisearch. I have installed the plugins in kibana and elasticsearch, but periodically elasticsearch print this stacktrace:

```
elasticsearch_1  | {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-10-07T08:07:38,744Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "c.a.o.a.MonitorRunner", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "474140009e51", "message": "Error loading alerts for monitor: PxkNAnUB9CNABdEIKobB", "cluster.uuid": "_FnIlDXOQHumHM4k50AP0Q", "node.id": "9j6JbC9QRVaSNAx78bMHDw" , 
elasticsearch_1  | "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: action [indices:data/read/search] is unauthorized for user [_system]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.support.Exceptions.authorizationError(Exceptions.java:34) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.denialException(AuthorizationService.java:601) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.authorizeSystemUser(AuthorizationService.java:392) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.authorize(AuthorizationService.java:193) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.authorizeRequest(SecurityActionFilter.java:173) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.lambda$applyInternal$3(SecurityActionFilter.java:159) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:63) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$writeAuthToContext$24(AuthenticationService.java:680) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.writeAuthToContext(AuthenticationService.java:695) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$handleNullToken$18(AuthenticationService.java:574) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.handleNullToken(AuthenticationService.java:584) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.consumeToken(AuthenticationService.java:437) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$extractToken$9(AuthenticationService.java:405) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.extractToken(AuthenticationService.java:425) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$checkForApiKey$3(AuthenticationService.java:366) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:63) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.ApiKeyService.authenticateWithApiKeyIfPresent(ApiKeyService.java:345) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.checkForApiKey(AuthenticationService.java:347) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$authenticateAsync$0(AuthenticationService.java:329) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:63) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.TokenService.getAndValidateToken(TokenService.java:405) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$authenticateAsync$2(AuthenticationService.java:325) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$lookForExistingAuthentication$6(AuthenticationService.java:384) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lookForExistingAuthentication(AuthenticationService.java:395) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.authenticateAsync(AuthenticationService.java:320) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.access$000(AuthenticationService.java:261) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService.authenticate(AuthenticationService.java:156) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.applyInternal(SecurityActionFilter.java:156) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.apply(SecurityActionFilter.java:108) ~[?:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:177) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:155) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:83) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:83) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:72) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:409) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.search(AbstractClient.java:542) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.alerting.MonitorRunner$loadCurrentAlerts$response$1.invoke(MonitorRunner.kt:334) ~[opendistro_alerting-1.10.1.2.jar:1.10.1.2]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.alerting.MonitorRunner$loadCurrentAlerts$response$1.invoke(MonitorRunner.kt:96) ~[opendistro_alerting-1.10.1.2.jar:1.10.1.2]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.alerting.elasticapi.ElasticExtensionsKt.suspendUntil(ElasticExtensions.kt:146) ~[alerting-core-1.10.1.2.jar:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.alerting.MonitorRunner.loadCurrentAlerts(MonitorRunner.kt:334) ~[opendistro_alerting-1.10.1.2.jar:1.10.1.2]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.alerting.MonitorRunner.runMonitor(MonitorRunner.kt:196) [opendistro_alerting-1.10.1.2.jar:1.10.1.2]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.alerting.MonitorRunner.runMonitor$default(MonitorRunner.kt:187) [opendistro_alerting-1.10.1.2.jar:1.10.1.2]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.alerting.MonitorRunner$runJob$1.invokeSuspend(MonitorRunner.kt:184) [opendistro_alerting-1.10.1.2.jar:1.10.1.2]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) [kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar:1.3.72-release-468 (1.3.72)]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:233) [kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594) [kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60) [kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:?]",
elasticsearch_1  | "at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742) [kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:?]"] }
```

How can i solve it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Open Distro alerting plugin is not compatible with xpack. Open Distro comes with built-in security, consider using Open Distro security.